# Convert pandas column values based on groupings of values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a pandas columns with values `1.0`, `2.0`, `3.0`, `4.0`, and `5.0` like below:

```
0       5.0
1       2.0
2       3.0
3       3.0
4       5.0
       ... 
1039    5.0
1040    1.0
1041    2.0
1042    4.0
1043    1.0
```

I want rows with values 1.0 or 2.0 to all have a value of 1.0, 3.0 and 4.0 to become 2.0, and 5.0 to become 3.0. How could I re-assign the values based on these groupings. I was thinking `np.where()` at first but now I'm not sure how to implement that with `np.where()` logic because that seems like it would be better suited for conversion to a binary variable. Maybe just masking with `.loc()`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your pattern, use simple arithmetics: add 1, get the floor division by 2:

```
df['new'] = df['col'].add(1).floordiv(2)
```

Or use [`cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html):

```
df['new'] = pd.cut(df['col'], [0, 2, 4, 6], labels=[1, 2, 3])
```

*Note that `cut` will give you a categorical type.*

Example:

```
      col  new
0     5.0  3.0
1     2.0  1.0
2     3.0  2.0
3     3.0  2.0
4     5.0  3.0
1039  5.0  3.0
1040  1.0  1.0
1041  2.0  1.0
1042  4.0  2.0
1043  1.0  1.0
```